# passing array to a jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am want to pass an array as a parameter of a jquery function. When I alert the array I get `function Array() {
    [native code]
}`

this error
I tried this in php. Here Sql functions are self written. They are good for sure. And throughout this loop I am printing the data from data table. Which works. Now I want to show other thing when button is clicked.

```
$i=0;
for(;$i<Sql_Num_Rows($result);$i++) {
$row=  Sql_fetch_array($result);
$j = 0;
$data[$i][$j++] = $row['user_id'];
$data[$i][$j++] = $row['first_name'];
$data[$i][$j++] = $row['last_name'];
$data[$i][$j++] = $row['user_address'];
$data[$i][$j++] = $row['user_phone'];;
$data[$i][$j++] = "<button onclick='update_user_info($row)'>detail</button>";
}
```

And this in javascript

```
function update_user_info(user_info)
{
  alert(user_info)
}
```

can anyone help me how can I get the array with value. array has value like `$row['name']`,`$row['email']`..... I need these values. Please help

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't seem very clear to me.To pass an array from PHP to jQuery you will need AJAX.

Comment: Actually i did not know that. So to pass variable from php to javascript i need ajax??If so please notify me. I will remove the question.

Comment: Because PHP is server-side and jQuery is client-side the *only* way to pass information between them is to use AJAX. If you're declaring simple variables you can do that when PHP processes the page e.g, `var foo = <?php echo $foo; ?>`

Comment: I don't think OP needs AJAX in this case, but to define correctly the parameter in the call. The array seems to be generated on page load, no need to use an AJAX call for this. @Md.MahamudulHasanKhan could you post the generated code for the button?

Comment: ok thank you very much i am removing my question. Now i know my approach was wrong

Comment: can u tell me how to define the parameter and what wrong with mine.